# create advanced HashMap, ArrayList, List

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to create a structure who looks like this using HashMap, ArrayList, List:

```
  [
    {
      firstname=Firstname 1,
      lastname=Lastname 1,
      detail=[
        {facturaId=1, date=2020/01/01},
        {facturaId=2, date=2020/01/02},
        {facturaId=3, date=2020/01/03}
      ]
    },
    {
      firstname=Firstname 2,
      lastname=Lastname 2,
      detail=[
        {facturaId=4, date=2020/01/01},
        {facturaId=5, date=2020/01/02},
        {facturaId=6, date=2020/01/03}
      ]
    }
  ]
```

My data structure looks like this :

```
| factureid |   date   | firstname | lastname |
+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
|1          |2020/01/01|Firstname 1|Lastname 1|
|2          |2020/01/02|Firstname 1|Lastname 1|
|3          |2020/01/03|Firstname 1|Lastname 1|
|4          |2020/01/01|Firstname 2|Lastname 2|
|5          |2020/01/02|Firstname 2|Lastname 2|
|6          |2020/01/03|Firstname 2|Lastname 2|
```

I'm not so familiar with HashMap, this is my attempt:

```
List<Object[]> results = Info.find();

List<Map<String, String>> detail = new ArrayList<>();

results.stream().forEach((result) -> {
     Map<String, String> detailMap = new HashMap<>();
     detailMap.put("facturaId", result[0].toString());
     detailMap.put("date", result[1].toString());
     detail.add(detailMap);
});
System.out.println(detail);
```

Print:

```
  [

    {facturaId=1, date=2020/01/01},
    {facturaId=2, date=2020/01/02},
    {facturaId=3, date=2020/01/03},
    {facturaId=4, date=2020/01/01},
    {facturaId=5, date=2020/01/02},
    {facturaId=6, date=2020/01/03}
  ]
```

Not the result I expected.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Why is it not a `List<Person>` where `Person` has properties `firstname`, `lastname`, `detail`?

Answer (score 0):

## Use objects, not arbitrary data

[Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)) is an [object-oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) language. So rather than wrestle with odd bits of data, we can organize that data into a class.

Java 16 brings the [new *records* feature](https://www.infoq.com/articles/java-14-feature-spotlight/) to Java 16, [previewed in Java 15](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/384) (and 14). This makes defining a class utterly simple.

You have persons with a first and last name, each holding a collection of invoices. So we need a `Person` class, and a `Invoice` class.

```java
record Invoice (Integer id , LocalDate received ) {};
record Person (String firstName , String lastName , Set<Invoice> invoices ){};
```

So we no longer need the `Map` you spoke of. We need only a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) or [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) of `Person` objects.

The [`Set.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#of(E,E)) and [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E,E)) methods return a [non-modifiable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#unmodifiable) collection. These methods provide a simple [literals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming)) syntax.

Represent your data example. I changed your second person’s invoice dates, and they contradicted the order of your example invoice numbers.

```java
List < Person > people =
        List.of(
                new Person(
                        "Alice" ,
                        "Applecake" ,
                        Set.of(
                                new Invoice( 1 , LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.JANUARY , 1 ) ) ,
                                new Invoice( 2 , LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.JANUARY , 2 ) ) ,
                                new Invoice( 3 , LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.JANUARY , 3 ) )
                        )
                ) ,
                new Person(
                        "Bob" ,
                        "Barker" ,
                        Set.of(
                                new Invoice( 4 , LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.JANUARY , 4 ) ) ,
                                new Invoice( 5 , LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.JANUARY , 5 ) ) ,
                                new Invoice( 6 , LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.JANUARY , 6 ) )
                        )
                )
        );
```

> people.toString():  [Person[firstName=Alice, lastName=Applecake, invoices=[Invoice[id=1, received=2020-01-01], Invoice[id=2, received=2020-01-02], Invoice[id=3, received=2020-01-03]]], Person[firstName=Bob, lastName=Barker, invoices=[Invoice[id=4, received=2020-01-04], Invoice[id=5, received=2020-01-05], Invoice[id=6, received=2020-01-06]]]]